# Discord bot is not responding to commands

Tags: node.js, command, discord, discord.js, bots

I started to make a bot for my Discord server, but I'm completely new to it (I have programming skills, but in web development). I made an application on the Discord developer portal, I made a folder on my PC, I created a `package.json` file, a `main.js` file, installed node.js, installed discord.js, I deployed my bot on a test server, etc. (not in this order but whatever).

Then, following a tutorial from a site, I made this in the `index.js` file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }
});

client.login(' I PUTTED MY TOCKEN HERE ');
```

When I put the command `!ping` on the test server I created, the bot remains offline and I don't receive `Pong`...

Can you please help me, please?

Comment: Did you run `node index.js` (or whatever your main file is) to actually start your bot?

Comment: How did you start your bot? Which file you tried to run? You mentioned both `index.js` and `main.js`.

Comment: I tried to run index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bot does not turn on, that means you did not correctly login or start the bot. Try to define `token` like `const token = "BOT TOKEN HERE"`, then put `client.login(token)` instead of what you have.

If that does not help, also make sure that you did `node .` in your terminal, which will start the bot.

So, your whole code should look something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "bot token here";
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.content === '!ping') {
       message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: What is defining `token` as a variable supposed to do?

Comment: whenever i write discord.js, i always define token as a new variable. I just suggested trying it.

Comment: Yeah, but how would it fix OPs problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your bot is allowed to recieve messages (discord.com/developers > your bot > bot > the two intent-switches).

Then add this into the brackets of new Discord.Client();
{ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', 'USER', 'GUILD_MEMBER']} (you can remove some of those parameters but message will be needed).

Sorry for bad English...